# Skobbler maps memory leak error in LimitOpenPackages::closePackage

Tags: ios, skmaps

So we are using skobbler maps iOS sdk and use crashlytics for crash reporting and every once in a while we get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS error. Pasted below is the stack trace.

0
Tripcipe
LimitOpenPackages::closePackage(MapPackage*) + 816407
1
Tripcipe
MapPackage::close() + 807806
2
Tripcipe
MapPackage::close() + 807806
3
Tripcipe
MapPackage::~MapPackage() + 806864
4
Tripcipe
MapPackage::~MapPackage() + 806774
5
Tripcipe
PackageManager::clearPackages() + 877506
6
Tripcipe
PackageManager::~PackageManager() + 876840
7
Tripcipe
PackageManager::~PackageManager() + 876750
8
Tripcipe
MapAccess::~MapAccess() + 262824
9
Tripcipe
std::tr1::_Sp_counted_base_impl, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose() + 323404
10
Tripcipe
std::tr1::shared_ptr::~shared_ptr() + 301834
11
libsystem_c.dylib
**cxa_finalize_ranges + 298
12
libsystem_c.dylib

exit + 12
13
UIKit

-[UIApplication _terminateWithStatus:] + 406
14
UIKit

-[UIApplication _handleApplicationDectivationWithScene:shouldForceExit:transitionContext:completion:] + 2416
15
UIKit

-[UIApplication workspaceShouldExit:] + 166
16
FrontBoardServices

__31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 16
17  CoreFoundation

__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 12
23  UIKit
UIApplicationMain + 1440
24
Tripcipe
main.m line 16
main

Does anyone know why this happens and how we can fix it? Or if it's maybe an error on Skobbler's side? Thanks for any help!

Comment: We've passed this question to the Scout developers